# Performance of nodejs filesystem vs .net System.IO?

Tags: node.js, filesystems, benchmarking, .net

I'm on a project needs do reading & writing ops to Windows server 2008 R2 filesystem. To achieve that I would think about using nodejs's FS module or .NET System.IO.
  Have someone do a benchmark between them? I appreciate if anyone loves to share the experience.

Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was curious about the same. I created a simple read-only test. I ran testing on on my src code directory of 19K files, 4K subdirectories, with a total of 850MB of disk space.

Runtime performance of .Net vs Node, in the case of a warm FS, was just about a tie.

The average of 5 runs gave the following times (in seconds):
Node: 3.037, CLR:  2.976

Post reboot, I'll update w/ cold numbers.

Code can be found here: https://github.com/ScottWeinstein/NodeVsNetFSPerf